# asiformdatarequest upload image,No file exists at (null)

Tags: ios, upload, asiformdatarequest

I use asiformdatarequest framework to upload images,The code like this:

```
 NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
    NSString *path1=[paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filename=[path1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"logo.png"];  
    NSLog(@"image path = %@",filename);
    [request setFile:[NSURL URLWithString:filename] forKey:@"avatar"];
    [request startSynchronous];
```

my log:

```
image path = /Users/tanlusheng/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/5473E6FF-0D3A-48CD-8728-0219CF25BC80/Documents/logo.png
Error Domain=ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=6 "No file exists at (null)" UserInfo=0x6b4c610 {NSLocalizedDescription=No file exists at (null)}
```

I have added one image in my project.but why it can't find the file?I run in simulator.

Comment: for path try - NSString *filename = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"logo" ofType:@"png"]

Comment: I tried your code,but it also "No file exists at(null)"

Answer (score 0):

When you're trying to send the image, you're trying to send an image from the application's `Documents` directory, and not the main bundle. Unless you've explicitly placed the image in the `Documents` directory (which you'd most likely do through code), it will not be there.

Try this instead:

```
NSString *filename = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"logo" ofType:@"png"];  
[request setFile:[NSURL URLWithString:filename] forKey:@"avatar"];
[request setDelegate:self]; //Make sure this class receives request alerts
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(someMethod:)]; //Which method to call when finished
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Note I've also changed the request to start asynchronously. You really don't want to upload synchronously or your app will stop executing until the request is finished. I've also added the self delegation and a selector for when the request finishes.

You can then handle the completed query here:

```
- (void)someMethod:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    NSString *response = [request responseString];
    NSLog(@"%@", response);
}
```

If you still get the null error, then make sure that the image has *Target Membership*. To do this, select your image in Xcode and make sure that the little box is ticked under *Target Membersip* on the right. This will ensure that the image is a part of your application when built.